# Cannot ping computers on another router

Tags: router, routing, home-networking, ping, subnet

I'm having issues with my home network. I have 2 TP-Link Routers (TP-Link 150Mbps ADSL2+ Modem Router, TP-Link Archer C20). Archer C20 is connected to ADSL router via WAN port (LAN port in ADSL).

Internet works on every device connected (sometimes there are issues with devices on Archer C20 - no internet available)

But I need to ping from PC1 to PC2 but in cmd it says "Request timed out" I managed it to work for a few seconds but then it timed out again..

With my last router, I simply connected seconds router not via WAN, but via LAN and everything worked but there is no such option on Archer C20.

Thank you for any help.

Here is my local network hierarchy:

EDIT: Due to a damaged cable between routers, I set C20 to wireless bridged mode which is now in the same subnet as ADSL router. Everything is working properly now :) thank you for your sugestions :)

[image]

Comment: Can PC1 ping the C20? Can PC2 ping the ADL2? I'm assuming yes. Then it means the routers are either blocking the ping request to go through, which makes sense, or the subnet can't address properly if you have route rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Make sure you have NAT disabled on your C20.
2. Try to put you C20 into a bridge mode, so both your PCs will be in the same subnet 192.168.1/24